# How to check if all the Network calls are done in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, dom, react-hooks

Is there a way in React to determine if all the Network calls are done or not?
For API calls I know I can use a flag to determine the loading state, but What about the images and other static resources?

**How can I determine that all the network calls(including images and other static resources) are resolved or not ?**

What I am trying to achieve is, I have to implement the loader, and fully disable the user interaction until we have a single pending call in the Network tab

Comment: Do you want to monitor the whole page load process or only a subset of resources?

Comment: I have to implement the loader, and fully disable the user interaction until we have a single pending call in the Network tab

Answer (score -1):

How about **finally()** function ?

finally() is always executed whether the promise is fulfilled or rejected. In other words, the finally() is executed when the promise is settled.

```
yourFetchFunction
    .then(result => {
        // process the result
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // handle the error
    })
    .finally(() => {
        // here 
    });
```

Comment: Where does the promise which determines when all the network calls are finished come from?